# FFMPEG outputs stream to UDP port, but no packets received on that port

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, udp, transcoding, opus

I am a bit new to FFMPEG and will appreciate any help I can get!
Basically, I am trying to transcode a 'webm' UDP stream to Opus audio stream, and then finally output that to a specific UDP port on my network.

This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:2222 -vn -map 0:a -c:a libopus -f ogg udp://127.0.0.1:2224
```

However, when I check on port 2224, I do not receive any packets.

FFMPEG is definitely receiving the input packets because if I run the following command, the file plays out perfectly:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:2222 -vn -map 0:a -c:a libopus -f test.opus
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what mistake I am making?

Comment: Format your code and be very specific about what behavior / errors your code block is having.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I am sorry but may I please know what you mean by formatting my code? The FFMPEG log shows no errors.